# Complete Maithili Maha Upanishad

Tags: rama, upanishads, sita, ramanandacharya, srisampradaya

**Complete Maithili Maha Upanishad which is found in Narada Panchratra Valmiki Samhita**

Answer (score 0):

**Complete Maithili Maha Upanishad**

Maithili Maha Upaniṣad is an Upaniṣad attached to Atharvaveda. This Upaniṣad's complete reference is also found in **Narada Panchratra Valmiki Samhita Chapter 5**. This is a very small upaniṣad with small 5 chapters. This, sings the divine Glory of Paratpar Par-Brahm Srimati Sita ji.
Here is the complete Upaniṣad :-
This Upaniṣad has also been said by Lord Shiva to Maa Parvati in Valmiki Samhita:

> श्रृणु देवि प्रवक्ष्यामि नित्यां शुद्धां सनातनीम् । महोपनिषदं
> वेदविश्रुतां वेदरूपिणीम् ॥१९॥

Lord Shiva said, "O Parvati Devi! I shall now describe the eternal, pure, ancient, and Vedas-famous form of Sri Maithili as mentioned in the Maithili Maha Upanishad."

(-Valmiki Samhita Chapter 5.19)

**Athah Maithili Maha Upaniṣad —**

नित्यां निरञ्जनां शुद्धां रामाभिन्नां महेश्वरीम् । मातरं मैथिलीं वन्दे गुणग्रामां रमारमाम् ॥ १॥
ॐ तत्सत् । रामरूपिणे परब्रह्मणे नमः। अथ हवैकदा रनसिंहासने समारूढां भगवतीं मैथिलीं लाट्यायनः कौञ्जायनः खाडायनो भलन्दनो विल्व ऐलाक्यस्तालुक्ष्य एते सप्त ऋषयः प्रेत्यतामूचुः । भूर्भुवः स्वः । सप्तद्वीपा वसुमती । त्रयो लोकाः । अन्तरिक्षम् । सर्वे त्वयि निवसन्ति । आमोदः। प्रमोदः । विमोदः । सम्मोदः । सर्वांस्त्वं सन्धत्से । आञ्जनेयाय ब्रह्मविद्या प्रदात्रि धात्रित्वां सर्वे वयं प्रणमामहे प्रणमामहे ॥
अथ हैनान्मैथिल्युवाच । वत्साः कुशलिनोऽदब्धासोऽरेपसः किं कामा यूयं प्रत्यपद्यध्वम् ॥ ते होचु र्मातर्मोक्षकामैः किं जाप्यं किं प्राप्यं किं ध्येयं किं विज्ञेयमित्येतत् सर्वं नो ब्रूहि ॥
सोवाच । राम इत्यक्षर द्वयं जाप्यम् । रिं राम इत्यक्षर त्रयं जाप्यम् । रुं राम इत्यक्षर त्रयं जाप्यम् । रें राम इत्यक्षर त्रयं जाप्यम् । रैं राम इत्यक्षर त्रयं जाप्यम् । रों राम इत्यक्षर त्रयं जाप्यम् । एतदेव हि तारकम् । एतदेव हि बन्धनबन्धनम् ॥ सार्द्धतिस्रो मात्रा ओमित्यत्र । इमानि त्र्यक्षराणि जपंस्तज्जपति ॥ त्रीणि वै दुःखानि । आध्यात्मिकमाधिदैविकमाधिभौतिकम् । इमानि त्र्यक्षराणि जपंस्तानि प्रणाशयति ॥ विष्णुलोकात्परे लोके साकेते शुभशंसिनि । राजन्तं रामचन्द्रेति जपन् बन्धाद् विमुच्यते जपन् बन्धाद् विमुच्यते **॥ इति प्रथमोपनिषत् ॥१॥**

परात्परतरो निखिलहेयप्रत्यनीकगुणाकरो जगदादिकारणममिततेजोराशिर्ब्रह्मादि देवैरप्युपास्यः स श्री भगवान् दाशरथिरेव प्राप्यो दाशरथिरेव प्राप्यः **॥ इति द्वितीयोपनिषत् ॥२॥**

सकलजगत्कारणबीजं भक्तवत्सलः स एव भगवाञ्ज्ञेयः स एव भगवाञ्ज्ञेयः **॥ इति तृतीयोपनिषत् ॥३॥**

ते ह पुनरेनामूचुः । षट्स्वपि मन्त्रेषु कतमो मन्त्रो गरीयान् । कमभिमन्त्र्य स्वकं कल्याणमभिपश्यामः । तन्नो ब्रूहि महेश्वरि ॥ सोवाचैनान् । सर्व एव मन्त्राः सुखप्रदाः शुभप्रदाः क्षेमप्रदा धनप्रदाः । एकमक्षरमुच्चारितं सदाजन्मभिरर्जितानि महापातकान्यपि विनाशयति । तत्रापि । षडक्षरो मन्त्रः सर्वोत्कृष्टः । आशुफलप्रदः । सर्वमेव वाञ्छितमभिपूरयति । मोक्षार्थी मोक्षं लभते । स्वर्गार्थी च स्वर्गम् । पुत्रार्थी पुत्रम् । धनार्थी धनम् । विद्यार्थी विद्याम् । यद्यत्कामयते सर्वमग्रतः स्थितमिवाभिपश्यति । ततः स एव सर्वोत्कृष्टः । स एव शिवकारणम् । स एव जाप्यः **॥ इति चतुर्थउपनिषत् ॥४॥**

इममेव मनुं पूर्वं साकेतपति र्मामिवोचत्। अहं हनुमते मम प्रियाय प्रियतराय । सर्वेद वेदिने ब्रह्मणे । स वशिष्ठाय। स पराशराय। स व्यासाय । स शुकाय । इत्येषोपनिषत् इत्येषा ब्रह्मविद्या ।
तेह प्रणम्योचुः । कृतकृत्या वयम् । विदित्तवेदितव्याः । पूर्णकामाः । संशयाद्वियुक्तः । त्वं हि मातर्नूनमस्माकं गुरुरस्माकं गुरुः **॥ इति पञ्चम्युपनिषत् ॥५॥**

**॥ इति मैथिलीमहोपनिषद् समाप्ता ॥**